# Google custom search removing \n from JSON

Tags: json

I'm using a Google custom search and the JSON that is returned:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCMGfdDaSfjqv5zYoS0mTJnOT3e9MURWkU&cx=017539885534136039129:1yf9jfaes0s&q=query%2Bterms

is inserting `\n` into my snippets which is ruining my formmatting. Any idea how to remove the breaks without using JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

An example on what I'm working on can be seen here:
https://www.connecttosupport.org/s4s/WhereILive/Council?pageId=665

I am using JavaScript to parse the JSON, but the search results on the text snippets have "br" tags automatically added by Google which can be seen on the JSON file above as "/n". What I need is to find out how to prevent the "/n" going into the JSON file,

Regards

Comment: Are you parsing this JSON with JavaScript or any other language?

Comment: First you will have to tell us what you are doing and with what language, possibly some piece of code. The way it is this question cannot be answered. Have you simply tried removing the `\n`? Keep in mind this is actually an escape code to a break-line symbol.